# Approaches to adding attachments in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm wondering what are some good solutions to adding attachments/files to records in rails3?

I'm talking about any kind of file, with user set upload limits.. Is this something paperclip can handle? If not are there any other/better/different solutions out there that people recommend I look into?

Or does anyone have any pointers for how I might go about this from scratch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use or `paperclip` or `CarrierWave` gems:

- https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip
- https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave

Usefull Ryan's screencasts:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

Both of them can handle a number of useful validations